# How to restart or quit/crash a .NET app (Unity3D game) when restart is needed? (Android/iOS)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mobile

After a user migrates game data from another account, the current game state is invalid, and the game should restart. However, Unity's official `Application.Quit` API does not work on iOS (at least, it didn't work last time I tried it). I could just block input on the screen so the user could not progress until quitting/restarting, but that's rather user unfriendly. Some mobile users don't even know how to quit apps! So it would be best to display a polite message, then restart, or quit or crash the app.

Things I've tried:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
```

The above works on some phones, but on others it just causes the game to hang.

```
System.Environment.FailFast("Please restart <game>");
```

On my phone, `FailFast` is not supported. I don't remember whether it hung, but it definitely didn't close.

Infinite recursion: I hoped a watchdog thread would kill the app, but no such luck. It hung.

Can I unload the main assembly? I could allocate memory until the OS kills the app, but that would be very impolite, considering other apps would also be cleared from memory.

My current plan is to use `Application.Quit()` followed by `GetCurrentProcess().Kill()`, and test on a few different devices, hoping that if the first API call doesn't work, the second will. Using separate separate native calls for Android and iOS seems like overkill, but that would surely work.

Comment: What exactly is your question? You have so many things in your title: restart, quit or crash....Which one?

Comment: If you want to make it crash, let it do a stackoverflower code

Comment: @Programmer As far as I know, I'm not exactly spoiled for choice. My preference is quit or crash, whichever is more likely to work on a variety of devices.